# Gatsby + Contentful + Netlify?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify

There is a gatsby starter kit installed locally.

It is associated with contentful.
In contentful I add posts, I launch gatsby deploy. Posts appear. Everything is OK.

Decided to deploy to nelify. Launched gatsby build, folder public poured on githab, from githab deployed on netlify.

And here it is possible to make changes in contentful, it is necessary to start assembly locally, then send to githab and start by deple on netlify? Can I simplify/automate something?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Contenful Webhooks](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/webhooks/).

Every time a data change on Contentful, a POST request is sent to Netlify, and this last re-trigger a build of your Gatsby website.

Comment: Thanks! This is what you need!